# How to implement a generic DAO object for Service pattern with Apex?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

Considering advice given for DAO objects or Service pattern from [What is a good set of coding conventions for Salesforce development?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/what-is-a-good-set-of-coding-conventions-for-salesforce-development), I'm wondering how can they be made generic enough?

Some generic DAOs from Java will solve that with an interface that has `find(id)`, `findAll()`, `search(ISearch)` and so on. The themes are that:

- the object is always returned in its entirety
- filters can be passed to search interfaces which is passed to the DAO to limit the wanted records

Now, consider the following code. It is a one-off selection to get some settings.

```
List<Foo_Settings__c> fooSettings = [
    Select 
         Id, Name 
    from 
         Foo_Settings__c
    where
         Status__c = 'Active'
];
```

Just some fields are selected. I'm worried that reproducing the Service pattern from Java might have a negative impact on:

- governor limits (I sometimes need only a couple of fields)
- flexibility (it is not clear in advance which fields and conditions will be needed. It would be great to have a generic DAO from which other classes would inherit)
- security (I imagine a lot of dynamic SOQL would have to be used)

Apex offers `query` and `queryMore` in `for` loops to balance heap consumption (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm):

```
for (Account a : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account  WHERE Name LIKE 'Acme%'])
```

How can a flexible and generic DAO class be implemented with Apex?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look into Andrew Fawcett's Enterprise Design Patterns Dreamforce Session, especially the Data Mapper (Selector) part

Source and links to the Video: https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-apex-enterprise-patterns

In addition check out https://github.com/apex-commons/SoqlBuilder (former apex-lang) on Github.

**Regarding your concerns**

*governor limits (I sometimes need only a couple of fields)*
shouldnt be a problem, as long as you dont 'lazy load' in for loops (e.g. retrieve 200 accounts and query contacts for each account)

*flexibility (it is not clear in advance which fields and conditions will be needed. It would be great to have a generic DAO from which other classes would inherit)*
Andrew's sObjectSelector in combination with apex-commons SoqlBuilder should do the trick

*security (I imagine a lot of dynamic SOQL would have to be used)*

use

```
public class MysObjectSelector {}
```

for your DAO/Selector, so you can enforce sharing rules or not depending on the context. For example your triggers run in system mode, so should your selector, but when using a visualforce controller you might want to enforce sharing by using

```
public with sharing class MyVisualforceController{}
```

Comment: There are some built-in limits for fields as well (mostly imposed by the number of characters in a compiled query), but great answer! Thank you.