# Does an Apex or VisualForce code style guide exist?

Tags: visualforce, bestpractice, apex, developer-productivity

Has anyone written an Apex or VisualForce code style guide, in the way of the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) or jslint, or PEP-8, or any number of Java guides?  I'm in the process on creating one for internal use but would love to base it off existing work, either by SFDC or a colleague.

In an ideal world, MavensMate and Eclipse can use the style guide for linting, but I'm happy with simply a programmer-readable textual version.

If no one has one and is considering employing one, would anyone be interested in collaborating?

Comment: Remember to think about constructs that are [unique to Apex](http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/apex-code-formatting/) compared to e.g. Java.

Comment: As far as collaboration, I'd be interested if you don't find a suitable version to work from.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've started on one... I think it's fair that we might disagree about certain ideas, but I think establishing the axes of disagreement is even procudtive (e.g., 2 space vs. 4 space vs. Tabs)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman No problem. I'll delete that comment and relink it here as related to avoid confusion. Related: [What is a good set of naming conventions to use when developing on the Force.com platform?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/890/what-is-a-good-set-of-naming-conventions-to-use-when-developing-on-the-force-com)

Comment: I couldn't find one and created one for my company internally, but can't share. :( I started with [Google's Java Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4-formatting) as a base for Apex and tweaked it until satisfied.

Comment: +1 for @PeterKnolle 's suggestion about Google's Java Style Guide.  I'm putting together a set of Apex / Visualforce coding best practices myself, and I started with the same baseline. It's an excellent place to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good set of coding conventions for Salesforce development?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/what-is-a-good-set-of-coding-conventions-for-salesforce-development)

Comment: From my point of view a style guide and coding conventions are related but not the same. A style guide explains how to use a language (e.g. is a bracket in a new line, camel case?, tabs vs. spaces). On the over hand there are coding conventions. They include patterns and more architectural and general thoughts.

Comment: @ChristianDeckert personally, I'd say style guide is a subset of coding conventions, and reviewing the answers to both of the possible duplicates the answers both tend to gravitate towards style guides (and using Java Style Guide as a base)

Comment: How about sublime?

Comment: Has a collaborative effort to create a style guide begun? As a newbie 3 months ago, this is something I was searching for myself.

Comment: @eyedar see [my answer below](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/54678/7195)

Comment: @sfdcfox see [my answer below](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/54678/7195)

Comment: I just found the official [Apex Coding Style Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Coding_Style_Guide). At the time of posting it is an empty page (LOL).

Comment: @sfdcfox - v1 of my own style guide for Apex is done.  VisualForce not started.  I'd love to know what you think on github.

Comment: @eyedar - v1 of my own style guide for Apex is done.  VisualForce not started.  I'd love to know what you think on github.

Comment: @PeterKnolle - v1 of my own style guide for Apex is done.  VisualForce not started.  I'd love to know what you think on github.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I started on [this style guide](https://github.com/PolarisProject/salesforceStyleGuide) months ago, made it open source.  I finally got it to v0.1.

The Apex guide is based on Google's [Java style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html) as [mentioned](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44460/does-an-apex-or-visualforce-code-style-guide-exist?noredirect=1#comment57580_44460) by [Peter Knolle](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/154/peter-knolle).

The Visualforce style guide does not yet exist.

The Salesforce admin style guide also does not yet exist.

The ant migration style guide does not exist, but I'm not sure it ought to.

Are there other aspects that I should consider?

Comment: Nice start.  One thing I'd like to mention.  SFDC being an online platform counts whitespaces.  Your indentation of 2 spaces literally uses double the space if you used tabs.  Over a lot of code this really adds up.  Normally I'd agree over the 2 space (or other arbitrary spaces #) but not on this platform.  My old company I worked for  agreed that for this reason tabs is far superior and I also brought this belief into my current company.  You don't have to agree but I wanted to make sure the character count was something you thought about and were aware of.

Comment: @dphil that's a great point. (I would rather pay that price in my small org, but I can see it being a problem in a larger one).

Comment: And what's to say your small org won't grow one day to become a large one?  Even if not large in data, large in code.  I always try to build based on the assumption that things will grow.  Sort of the same reason I bulkify triggers.  Sure we might only insert those records 1 at a time, but what if some day the process changes and we insert in bulk?  I mean I definitely understand the reason you have for the 2 spaces, just adding a separate view on it.

Comment: @dphil I agree entirely. That's why I wantinput from folks with more than my 12 months Salesforce experience.

Comment: @dphil I think v1 is done.  (yes, that was 6 months, but it was not high priority)  Please react on github.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Not a bad start. I've some ideas though. Should I raise some issues on GitHub, or how would we approach this?

Comment: @sfdcfox github issues and/or pull request i think.  let's keep the conversation at the source.

Comment: This guide could be a big help for me. I am not knowledgeable when it comes to establishing good coding style, is there any other way I can contribute to this project?

Comment: @smohyee How about an Admin style guide that focuses on naming conventions?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Are there plans to make an IDE linter based on this style guide?

Comment: @Xtremefaith I would love it, but I don't have time in my life.  Care to take that on?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Sorry I share that problem. I've also never done before so not quite sure how to set something like that up. If someone started a repo for it I could try to have my team add to it from time to time...

Comment: So happy I found this thread. I will join you on github shortly :)