# Apex: class naming conventions

Tags: apex

I've been coding Apex alone but now other developers will be involved so I am thinking about class naming conventions. This is what I was using:

Class: ClassName

Test class: ClassNameTest

Controller: ClassNameController

Controller test class: ClassNameControllerTest

Web service class: ClassNameService

Web service test class: ClassNameServiceTest

**1.** Is it good/bad?

**2.** What is the convention for utility class that contains static methods?

**3.** Should I add "Trigger" at the and of trigger class name? Some people suggest doing this but triggers are in a separate package with ".trigger" at the end so I find it not needed. Am I wrong?

**4.** What whould be the naming convention for the instance class which object exists inside controller class?

Comment: Take a look at this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/890/what-is-a-good-set-of-naming-conventions-to-use-when-developing-on-the-force-com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this question [What is a good set of naming conventions to use when developing on the Force.com platform?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/890/what-is-a-good-set-of-naming-conventions-to-use-when-developing-on-the-force-com) and [Apex-Code-Convention on GitHub](https://github.com/anupj/Apex-Code-Convention/blob/master/ApexCoding.txt)

As for me, I prefer convention on GitHub.

Comment: Convention on GitHub looks almost what I was looking for. It is strange that Force.com does not provide the official coding conventions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good/bad when it comes to conventions.

I have seen a lot of code and can assure you that people/organizations have their own naming conventions.

Here is what I do normally:

1. Triggers: `tgrTRIGGERNAME`
2. Classes: `clsCLASSNAME`
3. VF Pages: `vfpPAGENAME`
4. Controllers: `vfcPAGENAME`
5. TestClasses: `testCLASSNAME`
6. Utility classes: `utilCLASSNAME`
7. Classes which handle trigger code: `tgrCLASSNAMEHandler`

Comment: Sorry, I can't agree with you. For a person who always starts it's names from upper case letter it's hard to read your names.

Comment: As I said, different people use different naming convention. I just mentioned what I use for my coding. User would be concerned about is class name.... the indication I have in front of everything is tell the developer what is the user of this particular file... E.g. tgrCreateTaskOnJob will actually tell you that it creates task on Job and it is a trigger.

Comment: I understand. It's just I haven't seen anywhere such kind of naming and it seems strange to me.