# assign a value for output text from controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

how can i assign a string to the value of the output text from my controller?
Thank you in advance.

### example

```
public List<schedule__c> a = new List<schedule__c>();
public PageReference check() {

checkSched();      

return null;      
}
public void checkSched(){
    for(teacher__c teacher: [select id,name, First_name__c, Subject__c, Room_assignment__c from teacher__c  ])
    {
       if(teacher.Id == selectedtId)
       {

          string a = ('this is not available for' + teacher.name);

    }

}  


}
```

Comment: gelay -- you're killing yourself with variable naming issues - `a` is declared as a `List<Schedule__c>` outside of your method and as an error value in the method. Although these are in different scopes, you only confuse yourself and the community.  There are lots of resources on this, see for example - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/890/what-is-a-good-set-of-naming-conventions-to-use-when-developing-on-the-force-com as well as endless non Apex examples such as http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html#Attribute%20and%20Local%20Variable%20Names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a getter setter variable

```
public string strName {get; private set;}
```

And in your constructor or method

```
strName  = 'Test string';
```

And VF page

```
<apex:outputText value="{!strName}" />
```

And you need to use rerender attribute to get updated value of `strName`

Comment: @Ratun Paul.But there is rerender tag in OutputText..

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal have you  confused with rerender and rendered attribute ?

Comment: no there is rendered att but not rerender in output text.I am using same syntax but unable to get output text on vf page..