# How to automatically enforce naming conventions across a SalesForce organisation, as an Administrator?

Tags: naming-convention, automated-process

[Following another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/890/what-is-a-good-set-of-naming-conventions-to-use-when-developing-on-the-force-com/278346) that was asking what are good naming conventions for SalesForce, I have another question about how to enforce such conventions, automatically, if possible.

We are 2 SalesForce administrators in our company, and I'm interested in reducing the time spent on naming, by improving the UX when creating objects and fields.

Currently, when I create a new field, I type the "label", which automatically pre-fill the "name". But that "name" doesn't quite follow the conventions I'd like to use ([which can be found here](https://github.com/cfpb/salesforce-docs/blob/master/_pages/Salesforce-Naming-Conventions.md)).

Such convention prefer CamelCase over Snake_case, I'm not sure if that's a wise choice (does it has any bad repercussions?) but that'd be the way I'd go for it. But, SF autocomplete names using underscores by default, and I don't know how to change that.

Also, is there any way to show a warning when not following conventions? Or any tooling that could help to enforce rules?

Comment: Ditch the use of the Salesforce UI for metadata management and switch to using something like VSCode or IntelliJ IDEA + Illuminated Cloud. You can then add your own validation tooling (if there's nothing third party already available) that gets triggered before metadata gets pushed/deployed to any org.

Comment: Can't really do that, as the UI is used by non-developers admins.

Comment: OK, but that means you definitely can't enforce any conventions.

Comment: Too bad, I wasn't sure but I hoped I could. Like changing how the pre-filled "name" is generated